# Writing SQLiteOpenHelper test cases in JUnit4 and Mockito

Tags: android, sqlite, junit, mockito, junit4

I am trying to write test cases for my database.

I have a helper class that extends to SQLiteOpenHelper

```
DBHelper.java
       public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
```

and a constructor class that has all the inserts deletes etc.

```
DBController.java
      public DBController open() throws SQLException {
            dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
```

my test class

```
DBControllerTest.java
@Mock
    Context mContext;
    DBController dbController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        RenamingDelegatingContext context = new RenamingDelegatingContext(mContext, "test_");
        dbController = new DBController(context);
        dbController.open();
    }
```

Here when i do dbController.open(), the dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() always returns null.

How do i solve this problem. Also am I mocking it the right way. I have searched this a lot but did not find a solution. What is the best way to test database queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mock `Context` like that, you need to use the instrumentation's `Context`.  Since this test requires Android code and therefore instrumentation, make sure you put it in your test in the `androidTest` directory.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499554/android-junit-test-for-sqliteopenhelper) answer for an example.

Comment: How do i use a dependency for both unit tests cases and instrument test cases i.e. use mockito as both androidTestCompile and  testCompile.

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar Just declare it for both, eg `testCompile <mockito>` `androidTestCompile <mockito>`