# `RenamingDelegatingContext` is deprecated. How do we test SQLite db now?

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13556184/3286489, we could use `RenamingDelegatingContext` for aiding the SQLite DB unit test for Android development.

However in beginning API level 24, [android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/RenamingDelegatingContext.html) announced that this is now deprecated. So what is the new approach of testing we could do in replacing `RenamingDelegatingContext`?

Comment: are you running your tests on the device? have you weighed the option of using robolectric for some of your tests that would be better suited for robolectric on the jvm?

Comment: I have the same question. What little I have been able to research leads me to believe that the preferred approach is to use Mockito. I have not had time to experiment with this yet.

Comment: My preferences is not to have device test. But if that is what required, then I'll go for it.

Comment: @TrevJonez The Testing Support Library now offers functionality similar to Robolectric for local unit tests and is supported directly in Android Studio.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it is hardly the same. There are down sides to every approach but I would rather use robolectric and not worry about most mocking situations the way the official docs recommend doing.

Comment: @TrevJonez I guess I need to look into Robolectric more. The few times I tried it, I didn't have any success.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, check out my answer below. Using Robolectric successfully perform the needed test. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I'd be interested in finding out what a Mockito based solution would look like.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, what is this functionality you mentioned? Provided a link?

Comment: @NeonWarge I am not sure what you are referring to. Can you provide the exact quote from my comment that you are asking about?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this one "The Testing Support Library now offers functionality similar to Robolectric for local unit tests and is supported directly in Android Studio" I don't know what you are referring here either. You mentioned it is officially supported and I do not know what was officially supported. Link to the documentation helps.

Comment: @NeonWarge I was referring to running unit tests on a JVM on your development machine rather than deploying to an Android device. Prior to Android Studio 2.0, the only solution available for running local unit tests was Robolectric. Since AS 2.0, Google officially supports local unit tests without adding any third-party dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution, where we could just use Robolectric's `RuntimeEnvironment.application` as the Context, and the others would be straight forward as normal Unit test process.

In case if more details is needed, do refer to this, that has complete code of having Android SQLite DB unit tested. https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-sqlite-database-unit-testing-is-easy-a09994701162#.rhdv2qa9o

Answer (score 5):

If `targetSdkVersion 28`, you must add the following to your module's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...

    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}
```

By doing this, `RenamingDelegatingContext` and other missing classes will be available again.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Comment: Better to take a look at Android Test https://android.github.io/android-test/ and use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`